# How to do Pandas groupby with own criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Consider the following dataframe

```
d = {'N': [1, 2, 1, 2], 'NV': [50, 50,200,200], 'VAL' : [100,0,10,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

giving

```
   N  NV  VAL
0  1  50  100
1  2  50    0
2  1  200  10
3  2  200   0
```

I would like to groupby in order to obtain, for each NV, the number of VAL entries which are strictly positive. The result I wish to obtain is the following

```
   NV  VAL
0  50   1
1  200  1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: my bad. a quick google check fixed that

Comment: `df['VAL'].gt(0).astype(int).groupby(df['NV']).sum()` ..?

Answer (score 3):

`df.query("VAL > 0").groupby("NV").size()`

or

`df.groupby("NV").VAL.agg(lambda y: (y > 0).sum())`

Comment: But I guess you are asking about using lambda functions as part of `.aggregate`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df[df.VAL>0].groupby('NV').size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'VAL'})

    NV  VAL
0   50    1
1  200    1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
df['VAL'] = df.loc[df['VAL']>0].groupby(df['NV']).transform('count')
df.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.